# Python + OpenCV - Reading the image file name

Tags: python, opencv, imread

I have the following code snippet:

```
img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
```

When I `print img`, I get the result shown below. How can I return the `1.jpg` part only?

```
[[[140 149 139]
  [153 162 152]
  [155 165 153]
  ..., 
  [ 44  20   8]
  [ 46  22  10]
  [ 46  22  10]]

 [[151 160 150]
  [156 165 155]
  [152 162 150]
  ..., 
  [ 47  23  11]
  [ 48  24  12]
  [ 45  21   9]]

 [[155 164 154]
  [152 161 151]
  [146 156 144]
  ..., 
  [ 47  23  11]
  [ 49  25  13]
  [ 49  25  13]]

 ..., 
 [[ 28  16   6]
  [ 33  21  11]
  [ 32  20  10]
  ..., 
  [144 131 105]
  [150 137 111]
  [151 138 112]]

 [[ 33  18   9]
  [ 34  19  10]
  [ 34  20   8]
  ..., 
  [144 135 108]
  [143 134 107]
  [148 139 112]]

 [[ 31  16   7]
  [ 31  16   7]
  [ 35  21   9]
  ..., 
  [145 141 112]
  [137 133 105]
  [143 139 111]]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: `print type(img)`? What does it say?

Comment: When you load an image, it returns an array containing (what appears to be) the RGB values of the pixels. I doubt any return contains information about the file itself. But, either explicitly or passed through a variable, you know the name of the file. Why do you need it returned?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe `cv2.imread` returns a numpy array. So, there is no way to store the name unless you use a custom class.

```
class MyImage:
    def __init__(self, img_name):
        self.img = cv2.imread(img_name)
        self.__name = img_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__name
```

Then, you can use this as:

```
>>> x = MyImage('1.jpg')
>>> str(x)
1.jpg
>>> x.img # the numpy array
```

Comment: This returns the whole path with the image, is there a way to get only the file name?

Comment: @Ali123 what do you mean? Are you asking how to extract the file name from file path? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: thanks for checking, i found a. way to extract file name using os.path.splitext(img)[0]. i am not sure if it's the best option but it works for now